# Angular material sidenav error Found the synthetic listener @transform.start

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

https://stackblitz.com/github/snehalp29/ng10-material10

I am trying to use the material side nav but getting the following issue.

preview-29b0f46fcc27b310236ab.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
Error: Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

below is the code

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    Sidenav content
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content
    >Main content
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: So.. did you add those modules..?

Comment: Yes I have added those modules

Comment: I don’t see it in your ContactManagerModule..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error thrown is telling us that you must include the module "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your module.

If you module is AppModule, you have to include the import required by Angular Material, for example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    others imports here...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule <---- the import required!
  ]
})
```

Try it

Answer (score 1):

**The issue is your use of lazy-loaded modules.**

With lazy-loading, you have to ensure you're importing `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` in the right place.

It would be nice if adding the import in the lazy-loaded module that actually uses the `sidenav` worked, but the dependence on the `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` has to be eager-loaded, so it has to be in the AppModule or another-eager loaded module.

Looking at your code, you're lazy-loading the `ContactManager` module (i.e. [you use the `loadChildren` function](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)),

[image: example of loadChildren which is lazy-loaded module]

You can't add the import to a lazy-loaded module like `ContactManager`. Only your `AppModule` is eager-loaded, so you have to add the import to your `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ]
})
```

It's unfortunate that the error message you see isn't specific about this. It simply says to *include the dependency to your application*. It should say, *in an eager-loaded module*.