# ng test: Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

My `ng build` command works fine. It is only when I run `ng test` that this error happens:

```
Error: Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. 
Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 36945921, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0x: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 3391488, directChildFlags: 3391488, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Objens: '', name: '@transform', nonMinifiedName: '@transform', securityContext: 0, suffix: undefined }) ], bindingFlags: 40, outputs: [ Object({ type: 0, target: 'component', eventName: '@transfor'@transform.done', propName: null }) ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'craft-app-sidenav', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: 
at checkNoSyntheticProp (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/git/ttbt-craft/craft-angular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js:1198:1)
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push.../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.listen (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/Ctform-browser.js:1186:1)
...
```

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108364/angular-material-sidenav-error-found-the-synthetic-listener-transform-start), which has the same error. However, the previous question is probably running `ng build`, and doesn't answer whether they've included the modules (which I have done here, so it didn't fix my issue.)

In my case, I added `BrowserAnimationsModule` to:

1. app.module.ts
2. app-sidenav.module.ts
3. app-sidenav.component.spec.ts

Please note about above:

- In the first two "normal" modules above, I imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` files and added `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the `imports` array directly [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183802/1175496).
- In the third module above, the "test" module, I imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` files and added `BrowserAnimationsModule` to the `imports` array via  the `beforeEach(async(() => { TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)`, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234851/1175496)
- I've repeated the above steps using `NoopAnimationsModule`  instead of `BrowserAnimationsModule`, but still it doesn't work.
- I've imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` [after the `BrowserModule`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18751#issuecomment-418355790) (in the `imports` array), but I don't think order of imports matters...

Note the error complains about a synthetic **listener** (vs a synthetic **property**). I don't have any animations or `HostListener` or Angular Animations that I've defined in my code. However, I use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav), and the error mentions `@transform.start` , which is defined in the `MatSidenav` component from the `MatSidenavModule` (I made sure to import the `MatSidenavModule`) I [modified my components' `animations` property as suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52930613/1175496) (i.e. added the property `animations: [matDrawerAnimations.transformDrawer]` to my `AppSidenavComponent`, but it doesn't work).

My source code:

**app-sidenav.component.spec.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { AppSidenavRoutingModule } from './app-sidenav-routing.module';

import { AppSidenavComponent } from './app-sidenav.component';
import { AppSidenavService } from './app-sidenav.service';

export const APP_SIDENAV_IMPORTS = [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,

  CommonModule,
  AppSidenavRoutingModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  LayoutModule,
];

describe('AppSidenavComponent', () => {
  let component: AppSidenavComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppSidenavComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: APP_SIDENAV_IMPORTS,
      declarations: [AppSidenavComponent],
      providers: [AppSidenavService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppSidenavComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create including AnimationsModule', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**app-sidenav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, NgZone, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSidenavService } from './app-sidenav.service';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { FocusTrapFactory, FocusMonitor, FocusOrigin } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521339/1175496
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
// THIS IS NOT USED BECAUSE IT WOULD NOT CREATE THE DIRECTIVE AND EXPAND IT,
// EVEN THWN I EXTENDS MATSIDENAV
@Component({
  selector: 'craft-app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './app-sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class AppSidenavComponent extends MatSidenav implements OnInit {
  // constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _focusTrapFactory: FocusTrapFactory, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor, _platform: Platform, _doc: any);

  public opened: boolean = true;
  // compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppSidenavComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
  constructor(public appSidenavService: AppSidenavService,
    _elementRef: ElementRef,
    _focusTrapFactory: FocusTrapFactory,
    _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    _platform: Platform,
    _ngZone: NgZone,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) _doc: any
  ) {
    super(_elementRef, _focusTrapFactory, _focusMonitor, _platform, _ngZone, _doc);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggle();
  }

}
```

**app-sidenav.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppSidenavRoutingModule } from './app-sidenav-routing.module';
import { AppSidenavComponent } from './app-sidenav.component';
import { AppSidenavService } from './app-sidenav.service';

import  { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { APP_SIDENAV_IMPORTS } from './app-sidenav.component.spec';

@NgModule({
  imports: APP_SIDENAV_IMPORTS,
  exports : [
    AppSidenavComponent
  ],
  declarations: [AppSidenavComponent],
  providers: [AppSidenavService]
})
export class AppSidenavModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppNewFeaturesComponent } from './app/app-new-features.component';

import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    AppNewFeaturesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**EDIT**
When I use [this technique](https://kunzleigh.com/a-deep-dive-into-angular-test-case-setup/) (modifying `compiler.js` file, modifying the `_loadModules` function, to print the modules as they're loaded), I get output like the below (notice the `BrowserAnimationsModule` is among the modules listed! And yet still I have the error):

```
RootScopeModule
CommonModule
    NgClass
    NgComponentOutlet
    ...
ApplicationModule
BrowserModule
BrowserTestingModule
BrowserDynamicTestingModule
BrowserAnimationsModule
RouterModule
    RouterOutlet
    RouterLink
    ...
AppSidenavRoutingModule
BidiModule
    Dir
MatCommonModule
PlatformModule
ScrollingModule
    CdkFixedSizeVirtualScroll
    CdkScrollable
    ...
MatSidenavModule
    MatDrawer
    MatDrawerContainer
    ...
PanelBarModule
    PanelBarComponent
    PanelBarItemComponent
    ...
...
DynamicTestModule
    AppSidenavComponent
providers
   AppSidenavService
   TestBedViewEngine
   The presence of this token marks an injector as being the root injector.
```

Answer (score 0):

I made major changes since posting the question, and now my unit tests work better.
Here are some relevant changes:

- Upgrading Angular from version 8 to version 13
- So I upgraded all core components like @angular/core, @angular/cli
- And I upgraded all the key libraries I had to use, including @angular/material, and @progress (aka KendoUI)
- Use an empty array for the `styles` option passed to the builder, when running tests
  [image: empty array for styles option makes build run faster so angular karma tests can run]